# less command: b/f vs w/s

Tags: command-line, less, options

About the `less` and according with:

- [Less command](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Less_command)
- [Linux / Unix Colored Man Pages With less Command](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-colored-man-pages-with-less-command/)

indicates the following:

```
f ^F ^V SPACE * Forward one window (or N lines).
b ^B ESC-v *    Backward one window (or N lines).
z * Forward one window (and set window to N).
w * Backward one window (and set window to N).
```

Enabling the line numbers - with `-N` - for example for `man less` itself, I can see that `b/f` works/behaves the same than `w/z` it about the amount of content/lines moved up/down by either *window* or *page*.

**Question**

- What is the difference between `b/f` vs `w/z`?

normally I use the first pair, but when use the second pair?

**Extra Question**

- What does *and set window to N* mean?

I am assuming it is the expected difference that makes `w/z` different against `b/f`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try my best to explain with an example.

Open a long text file with `less`, something with obvious lines.

Now type `4z`, and you will see that 4 lines have shifted down.

Type `z` and another 4 lines have moved.

That `4z` has told `less` that you want the *window size* to be set to 4.

Once you have set the *window size*, all options (`f`,`b`,`z` or `w`) will now use that as the window size when moving through the text.

The difference is when `f` and `b` are used like this, they do **not** set the *window size*, they only move by that N number of lines.

Summing up with an example:

- `8f`: Move through the document 8 lines.
- `9b`: Move backwards through the document 9 lines.
- `f` or `z`: Move one "window size" through the document.
- `b` or `w`: Move backwards one "window size" through the document.
- `6z`: Move through the document 6 lines and set the "window size" to 6 lines. Using `f`,`b`,`z` or `w` after this will shift the document 6 lines.
- `3w`: Move backward through the document 3 lines and set the "window size" to 3 lines. Using `f`,`b`,`z` or `w` after this will shift the document 3 lines.

To reset the *window size*, you can type `-+z` (then enter).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Do you know if is possible reset the "window size" to its default value? it without exit/leave the current document opened with the `less`?

Comment: @ManuelJordan : Answer has been updated to include the reset options.

Comment: Huge thanks for the quick and polite support.

Comment: I confirmed that `-+z` works as expected, it resets either `<number>z` or `<number>w` - I read the `man less` and does not exist `-+z` but I found the information/description for `-+` that indicates _"Followed by one of the command line option letters this will reset the option to its default settings ...."_ so wondered why `-+w` does not work to reset `<number>z` or `<number>w`.